# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions after commit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having an exception when trying to insert an entity right after I had inserted and deleted it.

My code looks like this.

Those are the entities involved in this process:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProcessoNotificacaoPK implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3368326585727457799L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuario", nullable=false)
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProcesso") 
    private Processo processor;
    // getters and setters
```

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "ProcessoNotificacao")
public class ProcessoNotificacao implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 114301230965872905L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProcessoNotificacaoPK processoNotificacaoPK;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="pOCapa"), @JoinColumn(name="idPOItem")})
    private POItem poItem;
    
    @AutoGenerateID
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar")
    private ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processoNotificacaoAuxiliar;
        
    @Column(length=1)
    private String snPendente;
    @Column(length=2)
    private String tpNotificacao;
    @Column @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtAlteracao;
    @Column(length=2)
    private String tpProduto;
    // getters and setters
```

and

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar")
public class ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3368326585722309658L;

    @Id
    private int idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "Idusuario")
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProcesso", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    private Processo processo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value={ @JoinColumn(name="pOCapa"), @JoinColumn(name="idPOItem")}) 
    private POItem poItem;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({ 
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "IDPROCESSO", name="idProcesso"), 
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "IDLICAPA", name="idLiCapa")}) 
    private LiCapa liCapa;
    
    private String snPendente;
    
    private String tpProduto;
    // getters and setters
```

When saving an entity I'm using:

```
    public boolean save(T object){
        EntityManager entityManager;
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try{
            entityManager = getEntityManager();
            transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            
            Object key = getEntityKey(object);
            boolean persist = key == null || key.toString().equals("0");
            
            autoGenerateId(object);
            generateCode(object);
            generateMaxForCode(object); 
    
            if(!transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.begin();
            }
            if(!entityManager.contains(object)) {
                if(persist) {
                    entityManager.persist(object);
                } else {
                    object = entityManager.merge(object);
                }
            }
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and when deleting an entity:

```
    public boolean remove(Object o){
        EntityManager entityManager;
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try{
            entityManager = getEntityManager();
            transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            if(!transaction.isActive()){
                transaction.begin();
            }
            if(!entityManager.contains(o)) {
                o = entityManager.merge(o);
            }
            entityManager.remove(o);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and this is how I manage my EntityManager

```
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        EntityManager en = threadLocal.get();
        if(en != null && en.isOpen() && en.unwrap(Session.class).isOpen()) return en;
        en = emf.createEntityManager();
        en.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", CacheStoreMode.BYPASS); 
        threadLocal.set(en);
        return en;
    }

    public static void closeSessionEntityManagers(){
        EntityManager entityManager = threadLocal.get();
        if(entityManager == null) return;
        entityManager.clear();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

I've turned on Hibernate queries, and this is what is shown after the first insert:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        processono0_.idProcesso as idProces5_128_1_,
        processono0_.idUsuario as idUsuari6_128_1_,
        processono0_.dtAlteracao as dtAltera1_128_1_,
        processono0_.pOCapa as pOCapa7_128_1_,
        processono0_.idPOItem as idPOItem8_128_1_,
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces9_128_1_,
        processono0_.snPendente as snPenden2_128_1_,
        processono0_.tpNotificacao as tpNotifi3_128_1_,
        processono0_.tpProduto as tpProdut4_128_1_,
        processono1_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces1_129_0_,
        processono1_.idLiCapa as idLiCapa4_129_0_,
        processono1_.idProcesso as idProces5_129_0_,
        processono1_.pOCapa as pOCapa6_129_0_,
        processono1_.idPOItem as idPOItem7_129_0_,
        processono1_.snPendente as snPenden2_129_0_,
        processono1_.tpProduto as tpProdut3_129_0_,
        processono1_.Idusuario as Idusuari8_129_0_ 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacao processono0_ 
    left outer join
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processono1_ 
            on processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=processono1_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar 
    where
        processono0_.idProcesso=? 
        and processono0_.idUsuario=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces1_129_0_,
        processono0_.idLiCapa as idLiCapa4_129_0_,
        processono0_.idProcesso as idProces5_129_0_,
        processono0_.pOCapa as pOCapa6_129_0_,
        processono0_.idPOItem as idPOItem7_129_0_,
        processono0_.snPendente as snPenden2_129_0_,
        processono0_.tpProduto as tpProdut3_129_0_,
        processono0_.Idusuario as Idusuari8_129_0_ 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processono0_ 
    where
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar
        (idLiCapa, idProcesso, pOCapa, idPOItem, snPendente, tpProduto, Idusuario, idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ProcessoNotificacao
        (dtAlteracao, pOCapa, idPOItem, idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar, snPendente, tpNotificacao, tpProduto, idProcesso, idUsuario) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here is everything ok, the entity was merged () and after this when I delete the entity Hibernate shows:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces1_129_0_,
        processono0_.idLiCapa as idLiCapa4_129_0_,
        processono0_.idProcesso as idProces5_129_0_,
        processono0_.pOCapa as pOCapa6_129_0_,
        processono0_.idPOItem as idPOItem7_129_0_,
        processono0_.snPendente as snPenden2_129_0_,
        processono0_.tpProduto as tpProdut3_129_0_,
        processono0_.Idusuario as Idusuari8_129_0_ 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processono0_ 
    where
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacao 
    where
        idProcesso=? 
        and idUsuario=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar 
    where
        idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=?
```

Until this point everything is working, if I try to delete the entity again I get the following log from hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        processono0_.idProcesso as idProces5_128_1_,
        processono0_.idUsuario as idUsuari6_128_1_,
        processono0_.dtAlteracao as dtAltera1_128_1_,
        processono0_.pOCapa as pOCapa7_128_1_,
        processono0_.idPOItem as idPOItem8_128_1_,
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces9_128_1_,
        processono0_.snPendente as snPenden2_128_1_,
        processono0_.tpNotificacao as tpNotifi3_128_1_,
        processono0_.tpProduto as tpProdut4_128_1_,
        processono1_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces1_129_0_,
        processono1_.idLiCapa as idLiCapa4_129_0_,
        processono1_.idProcesso as idProces5_129_0_,
        processono1_.pOCapa as pOCapa6_129_0_,
        processono1_.idPOItem as idPOItem7_129_0_,
        processono1_.snPendente as snPenden2_129_0_,
        processono1_.tpProduto as tpProdut3_129_0_,
        processono1_.Idusuario as Idusuari8_129_0_ 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacao processono0_ 
    left outer join
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processono1_ 
            on processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=processono1_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar 
    where
        processono0_.idProcesso=? 
        and processono0_.idUsuario=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar as idProces1_129_0_,
        processono0_.idLiCapa as idLiCapa4_129_0_,
        processono0_.idProcesso as idProces5_129_0_,
        processono0_.pOCapa as pOCapa6_129_0_,
        processono0_.idPOItem as idPOItem7_129_0_,
        processono0_.snPendente as snPenden2_129_0_,
        processono0_.tpProduto as tpProdut3_129_0_,
        processono0_.Idusuario as Idusuari8_129_0_ 
    from
        ProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar processono0_ 
    where
        processono0_.idProcessoNotificacaoAuxiliar=?
```

and this error:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
    at br.com.bysoft.DAO.AbstractDAO.salvar(AbstractDAO.java:174)
    at br.com.bysoft.DAO.ProcessoNotificacaoDAO.adicionar(ProcessoNotificacaoDAO.java:275)
    at br.com.bysoft.DAO.ProcessoNotificacaoDAO.adicionar(ProcessoNotificacaoDAO.java:285)
    at br.com.bysoft.managedbeans.AcompanhamentoProcessoView.acompanharProcesso(AcompanhamentoProcessoView.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at br.com.bysoft.filters.ControleDeAcesso.doFilter(ControleDeAcesso.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.wrapCollections(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 48 more
```

I can't understand the exception clearly, it says that a collection is being associated with two open sessions.

This is what I already checked. Before saving the entities are always merged by `entityManager.merge()`, before deleting their state are merged using, and after deleting the entities are removed (validated with `entityManager.contains()`). My EntityManager instance is always the same (validated in `getEntityManager()` method). And my cascading for those entities are `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or nothing, as you can see in the code above.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

thanks.

Comment: Where do you close the `entityManager` obtained from the call to `getEntityManager()`?

Comment: Also, the fact that you get an exception trying to remove the entity again is not surprising at all, since the semantics of the `merge` operation are as follows: 'If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the
merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail)' (quote from the JPA spec). The question is: why are you trying to merge and/or remove a previously removed entity? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @crizzis, thanks for the answer. About closing the `EntityManager` I have a method for this (I've updated the question).
About your second question, the process is a favorite/unfavorite behavior (that's why the user can create and delete that entity) and since I was starting and committing a transaction, I believed that the entity can be merged or persisted again, is that right?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get an exception trying to remove the entity again is not surprising at all, since the semantics of the merge operation are as follows:

> If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail)

(quote from [the JPA spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)).

> since I was starting and committing a transaction, I believed that the entity can be merged or persisted again, is that right?

That would be true for a detached entity, but you're using an extended persistence context, meaning regular entities do **not** become detached after transaction commit, and removed entities enter the special `REMOVED` state instead (and then, trying to `merge` them back results in the behaviour I described above).

Also, even if they did, if you merge right before remove, you will never know if the remove actually succeeded or not. Instead, it will seem as though the removal *always* suceeds, even when the entity you were trying to remove no longer existed in the data store before the attempt. It would be more correct to simply use `entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(EntityClass.class, object.getId()))` inside your remove method.

As a final note, since it would seem you *did* expect entities to become detached after the transaction commit, I conclude you didn't realize you were using an extended persistence context. If you want all entities to become detached after every commit, simply call `EntityManager.clear()`.